# How to get an element of a NumPy list without bracket and ''

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy list (Distances). When I print it, the result is:

```
array([[  1.        ],
       [600.        ],
       [456.03971033],
       [294.94188261],
       [286.47232436],
       [ 92.08606785]])
```

However, I want to get any specific element of this list as a float number without any brackets, array, and '' sign. Note that I don't want to print it, I need to have the number in another variable like this:

```
element1 = Distance[0]
```

Result is: array([1.])

But I want it to be just: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first flatten the array to make it one dimensional:

```
flatdistance = Distance.flatten()
element1 = flatdistance[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2-D array, so you need to specify both indices:

```
element1 = Distance[0][0]
```

And the 600. will be at 1,0:

```
element2 = Distance[1][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your result is a matrix, (a list of lists in python).
So when you are doing `Distance[0]` you are correctly accessing the first element, that is a list. It has two dimensions.
So if you want to have that value you can do:

`Distance[0][0]`.

However, if your lists have always one element, try flat it with

`flat_distance = Distance[:, -1]`

And then `flat_distance[0]` is equal to `1`.